# Append custom data on a div when refresh page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On page refresh I want to append a random anchor from an array in a div.
My code looks like this:

```
<div id="exit-offer" class="exit-offer-dialog">
    <div class="offer-content" id="banner-load">
        <button class="close-offer" data-role="close-offer">&times;</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my js like this:

```
var exitPopLinks = [
            '<a href="#"><img data-role="offer" src="/img/exit-offer-v1.jpg"></a>',
            '<a href="#"><img data-role="offer" src="/img/exit-offer-v2.jpg"></a>',
            '<a href="#"><img data-role="offer" src="/img/exit-offer-v3.jpg"></a>',
            '<a href="#"><img data-role="offer" src="/img/exit-offer-v4.jpg"></a>'
        ];
$( "banner-load" ).append(exitPopLinks);
```

How can I populate #banner-load with a random value from the exitPopLinks variable when page refresh ?

Comment: Do you simply want to display a random banner? You can just use a simple `Math.random` to pick a random banner, so when you refresh it'll be random.

Comment: It's `$("#banner-load")` not `$("banner-load")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the code as follows:

```
var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*exitPopLinks.length);
$("#banner-load").append(exitPopLinks[index]);
```

I am updating the answer as requested, you can either put your link on `a` tag

```
var exitPopLinks = [
            '<a href="link1"><img src="/img/exit-offer-v1.jpg"></a>',
            '<a href="link2"><img src="/img/exit-offer-v2.jpg"></a>',
            '<a href="link3"><img src="/img/exit-offer-v3.jpg"></a>',
            '<a href="link4"><img src="/img/exit-offer-v4.jpg"></a>'
        ];
```

or you can add the following code after adding the element.

```
var linkUrl = ['l1','l2','l3','l4']
$("#banner-load a").bind("click",{},onLinkClicked);
function onLinkClicked(e){
   window.location = linkUrl[index];
}
```

Comment: this works perfectly. thank you.
I also need to make a window.location = url;
How can I put the right url here on click-ing the image ?
I have something else that make window.location.reload();  and I have to rewrite somehow this action.

Comment: should be something like this:
$('#exit-offer [data-role="offer"]').click(function (e) {
            window.location = 'http://google.ro';
        });

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Math.random()` to generate the random numbers. refer to [W3Schools JS Random](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_random.asp) - [Example](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_random_0_9) to know more about it.

```js
var exitPopLinks = [
            '<a href="#"><img src="/img/exit-offer-v1.jpg"></a>',
            '<a href="#"><img src="/img/exit-offer-v2.jpg"></a>',
            '<a href="#"><img src="/img/exit-offer-v3.jpg"></a>',
            '<a href="#"><img src="/img/exit-offer-v4.jpg"></a>'
        ];
// get the random number from 0 to length of array
var position = Math.floor(Math.random()*exitPopLinks.length);

$("#banner-load").append(exitPopLinks[position]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="exit-offer" class="exit-offer-dialog">
    <div class="offer-content" id="banner-load">
        <button class="close-offer" data-role="close-offer">&times;</button>
    </div>
</div>
```